# Sharing data amongst android applications running in many device

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I need to design an android model so that I could share some data amongst all users using my applications . I dont want to use push notification cause these sharing of data will happen too often, say every 15-20 second. Can i use HTTP post or something else to send data from one application to another.

Answer (score 2):

I think, the better solution is to implement a server, that would store the actual data and share it will all devices. This kind of architecture is easier to implement and to manage.

Comment: thnkx.Are you talking about implementing C2DM server. I want to know,if i use push notification in every 15-20 second,is it going to consume a lot battery or not.

Comment: @Naba, it also can be a C2DM server, or a simple server with it's own protocol of message exchange. I'm not aware of how push notifications are more battery consumable compared to a simple internet communication, so can't tell you much about it. I'd say that your application should be maximum user friendly to not drain the battery quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a server which will maintain all the data. Let your apps sync to this server, or let them open a socket to your server to retrieve the information immediately